# Pretrained model for Biomedical Image Segmentation

Tags: keras, pre-trained-model

I would like to use pre-trained model (in encoder part) for Biomedical Image segmentation with Unet architecture.

My question is which pre-trained model should I use?

I tried VGG16 and VGG19 with the following different options but I could not get an improvement:

1- I froze all layers of both models and the rest of the layers are trainable

2- I froze first 16 layers then first 11 layers, the rest of the layers are trainable

3 - I made all layers trainable.

Comment: I depends heavily on your data. I assume it's very different from imagenet.

Comment: I am using DRIVE database which is simply retinal vessel images

Comment: Your question is way too broad. I'd advise to review something like this https://www.kaggle.com/c/human-protein-atlas-image-classification